# How to include another file in an extended JavaScript file for Adobe

Tags: javascript, include, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I have found several sources such as this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375138/need-to-json-stringify-an-object-in-extendscript) where this questions seems to already be answered. However, it is not working for me and I have no idea why.

Here is a sample of my code, but it is basically only the first line which is of interest.

```
#include "json2.js";

var pdfOptions = app.preferences.PDFFileOptions;
pdfOptions.pDFCropToBox = PDFBoxType.PDFBOUNDINGBOX;
pdfOptions.pageToOpen = 1;

// Open a file using these preferences
var fileRef = new 
File("C:/originalpeople/Winetumbler/canvas_test1.pdf");
```

I get an Error 27: Stack overrun error.

Any help would be much appreciated.